# Считывание текста при скролинге,сохранение этого текста в документ на SWIFTе

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Здравствуйте друзья! Начал изучать язык SWIFT для тестирования приложения используя его в XCode и столкнулся с такой задачей.
Есть приложение. При запуске открываеться страница на которой есть горизонтальный скролинг.В этом скролинге находяться интерактивные темы( штук 10 по умолчанию) и их колличество может меняться в зависимости от конфига который использует пользователь. Хотел автоматизировать процесс сравнивания названий этих тем со списком который храниться на локальном диске.
Помогите пожалуйста понять как реализовать первую часть моей задачи - Поиск по тексту в этой скроллинг полоске и составление списка этого текста.
Спасибо.

Начало кода так,а как дальше создать список не знаю((((.

```
func testExample() {
    XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .faceUp

    
    
    let scrollView =
         XCUIApplication().children(matching: .window)
            .element(boundBy: 0)
            .children(matching: .other)
            .element.children(matching: .other)
            .element.children(matching: .other)
            .element.children(matching: .other)
            .element.children(matching: .other)
            .element(boundBy: 0)
            .children(matching: .other)
            .element(boundBy: 1)
            .children(matching: .other)
            .element(boundBy: 0)
            .children(matching: .scrollView)
            .element
    
    
    
    

    
    
  //  var lists = ["Annotate a File","Start from Scratch","Annotate a Webpage","Annotate a Video","Annotate Images","Annotate a Map","Annotate a File","Create a Live Stream","News Studio","Talk Show","Lincoln Memorial","The Not Perfect Hat Club","News Cast","BusinessCast","SportsCast","Here's How","Review It","Loading Theme...","Unable to Load Theme :("]
    
    
    
    scrollView.swipeRight()

  
    
    
    
 /*
     
    for text in lists {
        if text == "Loading Theme..." {
        repeat {
            sleep (30)
            scrollView.swipeRight()
            scrollView.swipeLeft()
        }
        }
        while text != "Loading Theme..."
    }
    scrollView.swipeRight()
    
        
    for text in lists {
        if text == "Unable to Load Theme :(" {
            XCUIApplication().buttons[text+" is logged"].tap()
            XCUIApplication().navigationBars[text].buttons["Settings"].tap()
            XCUIApplication().tables.buttons["Log Out"].tap()
            XCUIApplication().buttons["Sign In"].tap()
        }

    }
    
     
     */


    
 /*      let file = "file.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it
    
    let text = "_previewTitle" //just a text
    
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
        
        //writing
        do {
            try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch {/* error handling here */}
        
        
    }
        func writeToDocumentsFile(fileName:String,value:String) {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
            let path = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            do{
                try value.write(toFile: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }catch{
            }
        }
    */
    
    
    
    
    
    }
}
```

Пример текста на картинке:
[image: так начинаеться полоса прокрутки с темами]

Comment: Что есть эта полоска? Обычный UIScrollView или UICollectionView/еще что?

Comment: Xcode показывает следующую информацию :<ThemesSelectionScrollView>

<PagingScrollView: baseClass = UIScrollView; >

Comment: Также я понял,что названия тем являються: UILabel.  Как мне составить список этих тем?

Comment: На англоязычном сайте выложил этот же вопрос но немного изменил код,возможно по этому сценарию будет проще рещить эту задачу https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675798/how-can-i-save-the-title-of-my-theme-at-scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тестах около 0, но попробуйте направление:

```
let scrollView = XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Scroll View"]
let elementsQuery = scrollView.otherElements
let names = ["Label", "Label1", "Label12", "Label121" /*Label123 in program*/]
for element in elementsQuery.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex {
    // Замените на собственную логику
    XCTAssert(names.contains(element.label), "Not contains in names array")
}
```

Разбор:

0 Подготовка. Шлепнул UIScrollView с 4 UILabel в которых текст "Label", "Label1", "Label12", "Label123" соответственно. В тесте указываю:

```
let names = ["Label", "Label1", "Label12", "Label121"]
```

при проверке он должен упасть. Если заменить последний элемент на Label123, он должен пройти. Это для наглядности.

1 Получаем наш `UIScrollView`, "Scroll View" - это `accessibilityLabel` у меня:

```
let scrollView = XCUIApplication().scrollViews["Scroll View"]
```

2 Берем дочерние элементы:

```
let elementsQuery = scrollView.otherElements
```

3 Проходимся по ним циклом и получаем текст:

```
for element in elementsQuery.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex {
    XCTAssert(names.contains(element.label), "Not contains in names array")
}
```

Здесь можете заменить на то что необходимо. Т.е. можете пройтись циклом, сложить все в массив и дальше что-то с ним делать:

```
var labelNames = [String]()
for element in elementsQuery.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex {
    labelNames.append(element.label)
}
print(labelNames)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!